# Liquibase MySQL: syntax error near '????????????????'

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I am trying to run liquibase with following parameters (default parameters, just modified paths):

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
     --classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar
     --changeLogFile=changelog.xml \
     --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/example" \
     --username=root \
     migrate
```

changelog.xml is very minimal:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   <databaseChangeLog  
 xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"  
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
          http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">  
 </databaseChangeLog>
```

And the error I get is:

> Liquibase Update Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1 SEVERE 6/5/12 2:42
>   a.m.:liquibase: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '????????????????' at line 1
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????' at
>   line 1    at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:111)
>   at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:745)
>   at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:134) Caused
>   by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '????????????????' at line 1    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1049)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionImpl.java:1943)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3541)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2443)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2213)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:797)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
>   at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:101)
>   ...2 more

Have no idea what could cause it. I am running liquibase 2.0.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a very similar problem, and the '????????????????' made me suspect a charset issue.  Appending:

```
  ?useJvmCharsetConverters=true
```

to the url string in liquibase.properties, as suggested in [this post](http://www.vanheusden.com/java/tt.php), fixed it for me.

I would suggest you try replacing:

```
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/example"
```

by:

```
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/example?useJvmCharsetConverters=true"
```

in your liquibase command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The server, on which the problem had occurred is not running anymore so I can't tell whether it would have fixed it, but thanks anyway! maybe will help some one else in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the version of the MySQL server does not match the JDBC client jar which you are using. Version 5.1 is now quite old, the latest  version of MySQL is 5.6

To investigate this you could use liquibase to generate a SQL file and try running this against your database using a tool like [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html).

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
     --classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar
     --changeLogFile=changelog.xml \
     --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/example" \
     --username=root \
     updateSQL
```

## Update

I ran my example using debug as follows:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --logLevel=debug --logFile=update.log updateSQL
```

Produces a log file as follows:

```
DEBUG 13/06/12 19:08:liquibase: Unable to load/access Apache Derby driver class to check version
DEBUG 13/06/12 19:08:liquibase: Connected to liquibase@localhost@jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibase
INFO 13/06/12 19:08:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
DEBUG 13/06/12 19:08:liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT MD5SUM FROM `DATABASECHANGELOG` WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL
INFO 13/06/12 19:08:liquibase: Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
DEBUG 13/06/12 19:08:liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT FILENAME,AUTHOR,ID,MD5SUM,DATEEXECUTED,ORDEREXECUTED,TAG,EXECTYPE FROM `DATABASECHANGELOG` ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
..
..
```

Reproduced the same Apache Derby message (which looks to me like a default database check).

The important point is whether the MySQL connection message appears in your logfile?

As you can see Liquibase then performs SQL statements against it's DATABASECHANGELOG table to determine the status of the DB schema.

Comment: But 5.1.20 is the newest version of J Connector. The server is running MySQL 5.5.20 which is supported by 5.1.X connector according to Docs.

Comment: @Gediminas What does the generated SQL look like? I have tried to reproduce your error and failed.

Comment: I am really sorry for such a slow response. It's the same error (check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1). I also tried to set log level to debug, gives one more additional line:
`DEBUG 6/13/12 1:08 a.m.:liquibase: Unable to load/access Apache Derby driver class to check version
`
Does not display any queries though.

Comment: @Gediminas Apache Derby? But your JDBC URL is attempting to connect to MySQL? Very odd.

Comment: no, MySQL message does not appear. Only that first one, Derby. Although if I change user name to some invalid, non-existing, or do the same with database name it prints MySQL error that unable to find specified database or access denied for user.
`java --version` output is:

`java version "1.5.0"`

`gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)`

Server is running 64bit CentOS 6.2 with kernel version 2.6.32-042stab055.12